# How to tag friends in a wall post using facebbok sdk in android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am trying to tag one friend in my wall post. But this 'tags' parameter isn't working. How can i tag one/more friends? Pls help me. Thank you in advance.

```
            Bundle params = new Bundle();

            params.putString("tags", tagged_friends_id);

             WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this, Session.getActiveSession(),params))
                        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                            if (error == null) {
                                final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                                if (postId != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Posted story, id: "+postId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } 
                                else {
                                    // User clicked the Cancel button
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } 
                            else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                // User clicked the "x" button
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } 
                            else {
                                // Generic, ex: network error
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error posting story", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                    }).build();
                feedDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ming have mentioned, you can not tag friends using the **Feed Dialog**.

The only way to tag friends in a post, is using the Open Graph Concept- [**Mention Tagging**](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/21/bringing-mention-tagging-to-open-graph/)

Answer (score 1):

You can tag multiple friends using the "tags" key itself.
But the syntax needs to be bit different. The friend ids must be appended in a string separated by comma. There should not be any spaces between the ids.

For eg:

```
params.putString("tags", "xxxxx1,xxxxx2");
```

This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: by using your code i am getting an error of "error_code":100,"error_msg":"param tags must be non-empty.

Comment: i got it working as follow for(int i=0;i<ShareTripActivity.arr_facebookID.size();i++)
   {
    //ShareTripActivity.arr_facebookID = ShareTripActivity.arr_facebookID.substring(0, ShareTripActivity.arr_facebookID.length()-1);
    tagFriendListId = tagFriendListId+"{'tag_uid':'"+ShareTripActivity.arr_facebookID.get(i)+"'} ,";
    //tagFriendListId = tagFriendListId+ShareTripActivity.arr_facebookID.get(i)+","; 
   }
   
   tagFriendListId=tagFriendListId.substring(0, tagFriendListId.length()-1);
params.putString("tags","["+tagFriendListId+"]");

Comment: Any additional permission for tagging required??

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for the supported parameters to the Feed dialog here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

The Feed dialog does not support "tags".