# Post a status in facebook and tag friends

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to post a status on users own wall and tag the friends on it.
I tried FeedDialogBuilder but i can't tag friends with it.Please help me if anyone know how to do it.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();

    params.putString("tags","8768XXX787,"1111XXXX222,"565XXX566565");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(), Session.getActiveSession(),params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                    if (error == null) {
                        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                        if (postId != null) 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Posted story, id: "+postId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } 
                        else {
                            // User clicked the Cancel button
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),  "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } 
                    else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                        // User clicked the "x" button
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),  "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } 
                    else {
                        // Generic, ex: network error
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error posting story", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }).build();
    feedDialog.show();
```

Comment: Please show your current codes, thanks.

Comment: I am stuck with this for days.please help me.

Comment: Just searched in Stack Overflow, take a look at <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144959/how-to-tag-friends-in-a-wall-post-using-facebbok-sdk-in-android>